# How to plot two horizontal bars for each feature on a graph with matplotlib in a machine learning project

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Here is the code I am writing, however I was unable to double the bar for each feature:

```
[Xr ,Yr ,feat_names] = load_dataset_sc('boavista_covid_dados_abertos_reduzida.csv')

for f in range (len(feat_names)):
    if(Yr[f]) == 1:
        plt.barh(feat_names[f], (100*np.sum(Xr[:,f])/Xr.shape[0])-0.3)
    else:
        plt.barh(feat_names[f], 100*np.sum(Xr[:,f])/Xr.shape[0])
plt.show()
```

The return has been this:
[image: obtained return]

But I expect something like this:
[image: expected return, this is just an example figure.]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Have a look on [this docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html). It is better, if you generate your example data here instead of loading some obscure data-set

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).